# django 'unicode' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: django, forms, validation

I want to validate my form where user can not upload image of size greater than 512 Kb... My validation works perfect if the file size is greater than 512 Kb but when I upload nothing it gives error saying `unicode object has no attribute size` but I have checked that the image should be true

```
class GeneralUserPictureChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = GeneralUser
    fields = ("thumbnail",)

def clean_thumbnail(self):
    thumbnail = self.cleaned_data['thumbnail']
    if thumbnail:
        if thumbnail.size > 512*1024:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Image file too large ( > 512Kb )")
        return thumbnail

    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded image")
```

Here if I upload nothing it should give error "Couldn't read uploaded image" but it gives error..

Whats wrong in here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do more than just check the image field us in the cleaned data. I suspect you can do something like;

```
if thumbnail is not None:
    try:
        if thumbnail.size > 512*1024: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Image file too large ( > 512Kb )")
    except AttributeError:
        # no image uploaded as it has no size
        self._errors['thumbnail'] = _("Please upload an image") 
return thumbnail
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case where someone uploads an invalid image, you need to check for an `AttributeException`, however you're not returning the cleaned data value, even if it's `None`. If you don't return a value outside of the conditional statement(s), your form will *never* be valid.

Use the static `.get()` method, present on all Python dictionaries, to get the `thumbnail` value. If the key isn't there, the return value will be `None`. Checking for a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist will raise a `KeyError` exception.

```
def clean_thumbnail(self):

    # .get() will return `None` if the key is missing
    thumbnail = self.cleaned_data.get('thumbnail')

    if thumbnail:
        try:
            if thumbnail.size > 512*1024:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Image file too large ( > 512Kb )")
        except AttributeError:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded image")

    # always return the cleaned data value, even if it's `None`
    return thumbnail
```